# Accept Multiple inputs with php to update a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, input

I'm working on a small project: a small number crunching game.

I want to have a php file that can accept inputs and interpret them into specified database updates.

Here is what I have so far.  It doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
$name = $_GET['n'];
$action = $_GET['a'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Username ='".$name."'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($action = "rankup") mysql_query("UPDATE players SET Level 'Level+1' WHERE Username='".$name."'");
}

mysql_close($con);
```

I'm not getting any errors, but its not working, and all the database connections are fine.

I dont know what the problem is.

Comment: At first please use `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['foo'])` for every user input you pass to the DB. Second, you should use the more "modern" way of accessing the DB with PHP `PDO` (see http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: First of all the database functions you are using are obsolete. You should use mysqli_query and mysqli_close not mysql.

Comment: To block sql injection attacks right?

Comment: Explain how it's not working.

Comment: Well, its the database entries are not being updated. Its not showing any error.

Comment: Didn't you mean `SET Level=Level+1` ?

Comment: -_- Lafor, it fixed it, @fdomig, thanks for that, Ill use that. :)

Comment: Please check the hints you got from @Ugo Méda's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several mistakes here :

- You're not sanitizing your inputs, please read about [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- You're not checking the output of your `mysql_query`. The query with `SET Level 'Level+1'` is invalid, you forgot a `=` and remove quotes
- `$action == 'rankup'`, not `=`
- Please consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for new projects, it's a way better interface than `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You want to enter your sql query like this

```
'UPDATE players SET Level= (Level+1)  WHERE Username='.$name.'
```

Also any database function that begins with mysql should be replaced with mysqli. This is because PHP is phasing out functions beginning with mysql in the next edition.